# Authenticate external create-react-app custom app with shopify

Tags: reactjs, shopify, create-react-app, shopify-app

I've been trying to find the appropriate resources for the last 2 days but all resources I find are for embedded apps and I hope someone can point me in the right direction at least.

I have an external CRA custom app that I **don't** want embedded in the shopify admin. It is a custom dashboard pulling information from Sanity IO not for customers. Some of the same information is also being pulled into Shopify and displayed on the storefront.

Question is how do I authenticate the app from the CRA front? I can get to the redirect address with the hmac and shop url params.. but what then?

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

To connect your App to Shopify you still can do the oAuth dance. Has nothing to do with whether your App is embedded in the Shop or not. You would do oAuth with the Shop, get a token to do your API work, and save that token. Now the App is used OUTSIDE Shopify all you want, as you wish, but internally you can make all the API calls you want that you asked for scopes on.

Basically, just outfit your App with oAuth flow as per any other type of App that uses oAuth, and you're good to go.

Comment: Ok I think now that I look at it the question should be more how do I complete the oauth flow from within react after it's directed to the app? I actually think this is more a react question than a shopify one.

Comment: Have you find any solution to get this job ? I'm also trying to do this.